# SQL query for calculating account balance

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

I want to calculate account balance using raw sql without extra application logic.
Transaction schema includes amount, from_account_id and to_account_id

My query is

```
SELECT SUM(tdebit.amount) - SUM(tcredit.amount) as balance
FROM accounts as a
INNER JOIN transactions as tdebit ON a.id = tdebit.to_account_id
INNER JOIN transactions as tcredit ON a.id = tcredit.from_account_id
WHERE a.id = $1 AND tdebit.succeed = true AND tcredit.succeed = true
```

And it does not work as I expected - result is wrong, but if I join transaction only once it works correctly, for example just debit amount is ok

```
SELECT SUM(tdebit.amount) as debit
FROM accounts as a
INNER JOIN transactions as tdebit ON a.id = tdebit.to_account_id
WHERE a.id = $1 AND tdebit.succeed = true
```

What did I miss in my balance query?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5565/1

Comment: By *does not works* you mean, results are not the same then `SUM(tdebit.amount) - SUM(tcredit.amount) as balance` will always be `0` but `SUM(tdebit.amount) as debit` not.

Comment: Your query is working fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1219/2

Comment: @P.Jairaj consider modified version
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5565/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically calculating the cross product between a `tdebits` and `tcredits`, i.e. for each row in `tdebits` you are iterating over all the rows in `tcredits`.  There's also no reason to join to `accounts` (unless `to_account_id` and `from_account_id` aren't foreign keys).

You only need to do one pass over transactions and you just need to know whether the amount is a credit or debit.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.to_account_id = $1 THEN t.amount ELSE -t.amount END) AS amount
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE (t.to_account_id = $1 OR t.from_account_id = $1)
  AND t.succeed = true
```

If an account can transfer to itself, add a `t.to_account_id <> t.from_account_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate before doing the joins, if you want the value for all accounts:

```
select a.*, coalesce(tdebit.debit, 0) - coalesce(tcredit.credit, 0)
from accounts a left join
     (select t.to_account_id, sum(t.amount) as debit
      from transactions t
      group by t.to_account_id
     ) tdebit
     on a.id = tdebit.to_account_id left join
     (select t.from_account_id, sum(t.amount) as credit
      from transactions t
      group by t.from_account_id
     ) tcredit
     on a.id = tcredit.from_account_id;
```